# What is the success criteria for KLOC in each testing phases

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, system-testing, user-acceptance-testing

I was wondering what is the success criteria for each of the unit/integration/system/user-acceptance testings for KLOC.

Somewhere I heard that there should be no more than 5 compiler defects per KLOC. Is there such standard values for success criteria in each test phases?

Please advice me if I'm wrong. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be wonder about success criteria for different type of software testing. No more than 5 compiler defects per KLOC is not a standard but it's a well known term for testing. It can be said that if more than 5 compiler not find defects per KLOC than particular KLOC may be bug free. Coz. you know from testing principal exhaustive testing is impossible. From Testing principle it can also said that, there has no success criteria for testing, success of testing most of the time depend on software exit path criteria.